# What are some file formats used when writing an append only file?

Tags: performance, file-writing

So, I've been looking at a number of resources about performance issues surrounding writing to file.  I've come across the notion of Append Only Files and Transaction Logs.  What I have not found are typical formats, or efficient formats for these kinds of files.

I may be wrong, but it would seem that one could read and write to the same file at the same time, but I haven't found any simple implementation examples.  It seems as though the writer would have to leave behind details about the data found in the file, or perhaps a fully descriptive format that can be parsed.

Are there good references for how to implement a transaction log or append only file implementation?  Perhaps even better: descriptions of a formats used in append only files implemntation?

Comment: The ZIP format can work in append only mode. The only source of truth is the central directory, which happens at the end. It has caused pain for people trying to stream it head-to-to-toe, but welp. Or the ISO9660 file system on multisession CD-R!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad and it's hard to recommend a single approach. But since you're looking at an append-only option, you would need a format that doesn't require a footer. E.g. you can't use XML since XML has to have closing tags and you wouldn't simply be appending data.

An obvious option is a delimited file format, be it tab or comma-delimited text. They are practically universal and well-defined. They are also pretty compact, just one character to delimit fields. However, they are not good for data that changes row by row. E.g. one row has values for A, B, C fields but another row has values for A, D, and E fields. In that case, you might need a format that defines the type of data in a record per record. An example of such format is HL7 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Level_7). It's a delimited format but each row has a "header" indicating the record type.

If you're looking for a higher performance option, you can come up with your own format depending on your data, and even store it in binary format, and even use compression (See DeflateStream https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream(v=vs.110).aspx) to reduce file I/O. That will make write operations a bit more CPU intensive but I/O is usually slower so on the whole, especially since text compresses really well, you might end up with performance gains. You'd have to benchmark to be sure for your use case.

Finally, you would want a class that can manage the writing (cache/queue writes, keep the file handler, etc) so that calling code can be simplified and synchronized in one place. You can make that async, if the caller can move on with their work and your writer will ensure the data makes it in, or synchronous if this is a "transaction log," meaning, loss is unacceptable, and caller has to make sure write actually happened.

Again, this is very high level info since your request is just as vague and high level. If you come up with more details, maybe we can better help you.